# Text div wtih two colors

Tags: slider, swiper.js

this is the problem, I have a div with a blue background and above a div with some text, this div must have two different colors as the slide moves:

[text]`Codepen`(https://codepen.io/ilariotr68/pen/XWoZXxG)

I would like the "Individual & Family" text to keep the white color above the blue background and the blue color on the white background when dragging the slide